# MS Access Form Combo Box - Set Default to blank

Tags: ms-access, combobox, default, ms-access-forms

I have a combo box in a form that uses a query to get the row source (lookup list).  I am trying to set the default value to blank but nothing seems to work.  It still populates with the first row of the query result.  I am thinking it may be because there is no blank value in the list.

Here are the properties I have currently:

```
Limit to list - No
Allow Value List Edits - Yes
Inherit Value List - No
Show only row source values - No
Default Value ""
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This should normally not happen. Is this combobox bound to a query field? Does that field have a default value?

Comment: How about some other properties: control source, row source, bound column, column count, column widths? You should not only leave the default value blank but also remove the default value from the field in the underlying table of the form.

Comment: It was bound to a query field so I changed it to an unbound control and it worked.  Thanks Andre!